# How to create iframe with document in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to create an iframe element which has a document and a `<head>` and `<body>` in javascript.

**The iframe cannot exist in the dom.** This part is critical.

The following attempts do not work:

```
var frame = $('<iframe />'); // [<iframe>​</iframe>​]

var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument() // #document

// TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null
frame.append(doc);

// HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type '#document' may not be inserted inside nodes of type 'IFRAME'.
frame.get(0).appendChild(doc)
```

I also tried creating it in the dom, and then trying to clone it, but the cloned iframe no longer contains a document.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this? it will add content to your iframe

```
frame.contents().find('html').html("content"); //content: content of your document
```